# c# correct way to access private constant on other class

Tags: c#, encapsulation

If I have a class

```
public class Person
{
    private const string MyConst = "SomeValue";

    [MyAttribute(MyConst)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and inside other class I would like to access `MyConst`  what would be the best way to do so, keeping all encapsulated? Is it correct Person class?

Comment: public string Name { get { return MyConst; } };

Comment: Why do you want to encapsulate it at all, its `const`, you can't set it and you can only read it. Leave it like that.

Comment: so I would just make it public? and then create an instance of person in other class and then access `MyConst`

Comment: If you expose something outside of your class, it's no longer private. If it needs to be used elsewhere, maybe having it as a private member of your class isn't the best design.

Comment: `const` is implicitly static - you wouldn't create an instance.

Comment: There IS no correct way to do that. Its private, which means you shouldn't access it. You can use reflection, but it's still wrong.

Comment: @Justin Niessner could you please post a better design idea, to keep moving

Comment: @cMinor - To make an educated suggestion, you'd have to explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the protection you need on MyConst. If no body should be able to read or write this property other than Person then you shouldn't expose it through either Get or Set methods. If everybody can read but cant write this, then you can expose it through a read only property. If only one class (e.g. ClassB) can read it then you can provide a function in Person that takes a ClassB object and passes the private Const to it:

```
public class ClassB
{
    private string ConstValue {get; set;}
    public void SetConstValue(string constValue)
    {
       ConstValue = constValue;
    }

    public void GetConstFromPerson(Person p)
    {
       p.GetConstValue(this);
    }
}


public class Person
{
   private const string MyConst = "A";


   public void GetConstValue(ClassB obj)
   {
       //todo: contract validations
       obj.SetConstValue(MyConst);
   }

}
```

[Edit]

Another solution is to define the constant as Internal and only have Person and CLassB in the assembly

Comment: It's a constant. What would exposing it through a read only property achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to access `MyConst` from another class then you are no longer encapsulating it. Adding properties or method calls around this will not mean it is encapsulated. It's a constant. It cannot change. So either its publicly accessible or it's not. If another class needs access, make it internal or public.

Anything else is somewhere between denial and a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

make a public property that returns `MyConst`?

`public string MyPublicConst {get{ return MyConst;} private set; }` - but why do you want to do this?

Comment: It'd be better to just make it public. A property for a constant is kind of silly.

Comment: @AlexBeisley hehe yeah, my solution does seem silly now, that you've mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it public (Duh!), you can use a property to encapsulate it if you are planning on changing it from a constant to something else, or you could have a method that return it to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Encapsulation{ 
            private string a;

            public string AccessValue(){

                return a;
            }
         }
```

you can do that to any variable I think, for sure the simple ones.

This is a public method from the same class that returns the same value of the private string.
In that way you can get the value from outside the class without declare it as public.

To reach it from another class you can just write:

```
class Player{ string b = Encapsulaion.AccessValue()}
```